# How to list and remove files only if multiple conditions are met

Tags: command-line, bash, python, ruby

This is on ubuntu 18.04. I have access to bash, pip3, and ruby gems on this machine.

Trying to work with multiple mp4 files that were sent to us by VHS converter company. Each file has at least a version with 240p in the name and some of them have both a 240p filename and a 480p filename.

They stuck these hundreds of files in one zip and sent them to us.

If every mp4 file is in one directory, how could I find only the files that have both a 240p and a 480p version and remove the 240p version -- without removing the files that have ONLY a 240p version.

Comment: Please provide sample names of `mp4` files of each kind.

Answer (score 0):

With bash, you could run something along the lines of

```
for a in *240p.mp4
do 
   b=${a/240p/480p}                     ## replace 240 by 480
   if [ -f "$b" ]                       ## if x-480p.mp4 exists
     then   mv "$a" "REMOVE_$a"         ##   rename x-240p to REMOVE_x-240p
   fi
done
```

And if you are happy with the REMOVEd list

```
rm REMOVE_*
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing `mv`, better do `echo` without actually renaming files

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy, yes. `echo rm "$a"` and deleting `echo` if happy, sounds like a good idea.